# Look for a particular last character in a string using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following query:

```
DB::connection('mysql_cards')
        ->table('cards')
        ->selectRaw('colors, COUNT(*) as count')
        ->where('setCode', '=', $setcode)
        ->where('value', '!=', '140b')
        ->groupBy('colors')
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Basically I'd like to get values which do not have the 'b' at the end of it's string.

```
->where('value', '!=', '140b')
```

How can I write this correctly in Laravel Query Builder?

Comment: Have you tried `NOT LiKE` with a wildcard `%` -> `->where('value', 'NOT LIKE', '%b')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [Mysql Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)  `NOT LIKE`

```
where('value', 'NOT LIKE', '%b')
```

if you need specific `[0-9]b` format you can try

```
 where('value', 'REGEXP', '[0-9]b$')
```